# Getting all punch in and punch out of an employee?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdlc

My table is as below:

```
id       time_stamp                 evenid    
1001    2017-09-05 09:35:00         1(in)
1002    2017-09-05 11:00:00         0(out)
```

I used below query, it gets but not an exact answer.**Wrong** taking next day in desired date

```
;WITH InOut (empId, EntryTime, ExitTime,POINTID,EVENTID,Belongs_to) as
(SELECT  emp_reader_id ,
        a1.DT ,
        ( SELECT    MIN(a2.DT)
          FROM      trnevents a2
          WHERE     a1.emp_reader_id = a2.emp_reader_id
                    AND a1.DT < a2.DT
        ),a1.DeviceSerialNumber,EVENTID,Belongs_to
FROM    trnevents a1    

)
SELECT empId ,
       EntryTime ,
       ExitTime,EVENTID, Belongs_to
         ,CONVERT( CHAR(11), '2017/12/30', 103 ) as StartDate
      ,CONVERT( CHAR(11), '2018/01/15', 103 ) as ToDate
       ,case when convert(time,dateadd(ms,DATEDIFF(SECOND, EntryTime, ExitTime)*1000,0),114) is not null
        then convert(time,dateadd(ms,DATEDIFF(SECOND, EntryTime, ExitTime)*1000,0),114) else '00:00' end as Worked FROM InOut  A
```

Wrong Output: it get next day also

```
   EMP_NO       INTIME                OUTTIME             DT          WORKED
    101 2018-01-08 09:11:14.000 2018-01-08 12:07:22.000 2018-01-08      02:56:08.0000000
    101 2018-01-08 12:07:22.000 2018-01-08 14:35:33.000 2018-01-08      02:28:11.0000000
    101 2018-01-08 14:35:33.000 **2018-01-09 09:14:00.000** 2018-01-08  18:38:27.0000000
    101 2018-01-09 09:14:00.000 2018-01-09 14:28:23.000 2018-01-09      05:14:23.0000000
```

My Desired Output:

```
SL# Emp# Employee Name           IN                    OUT           Worked 
2   107    Nisham M    24/Sep/2017 8:34:00AM 24/Sep/2017 10:15:00AM 01:41:00
                      24/Sep/2017 10:19:00AM 24/Sep/2017 12:20:00PM 02:01:00
                      24/Sep/2017 12:25:00PM 24/Sep/2017 12:54:00PM 00:29:00
                        24/Sep/2017 2:13:00PM 24/Sep/2017 2:14:00PM 00:01:00
                        24/Sep/2017 2:19:00PM 24/Sep/2017 5:25:00PM 03:06:00
                        10/Oct/2017 2:00:00PM 10/Oct/2017 2:52:00PM 00:52:00
                        10/Oct/2017 3:15:00PM     NULL                -
                       11/Oct/2017 8:26:00AM 11/Oct/2017 10:29:00AM 02:03:00
                        19/Oct/2017 1:59:00PM 19/Oct/2017 5:56:00PM 03:57:00
Total Shift Hours Total Basic Hours OT Normal Hours Total Hours Worked
    210             159:20:00         00:00:00          159:20:00
```

i stuck here and search most but not getting desired output anyone help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get All punch in and out for each employee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205873/get-all-punch-in-and-out-for-each-employee)

Answer (score 5):

According [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592/1270789), adding:

```
AND DATEDIFF(DAY, a1.DT, a2.DT) = 0
```

To the `WHERE` clause should ensure the start and end date are on the same day, but what happens if someone works past midnight? Also your post suggests that you are picking up end times as start times also, so instead you could have:

```
AND a1.EVENTID = 1 AND a2.EVENTID = 0
```

If neither are suitable, please describe your problem further and provide some more sample data.

Comment: no not an answer i need..